# Why is there no in >> endl?

Tags: c++, iostream

When reading formatted input from a text file, nothing is more natural than skipping the end of the line.

Why is there no `endl` specifier for an input stream ? Instead it seems that we have to use the ugly

```
In.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35258696/stdcout-not-printing-the-value-with-out-endl-newline-specifier, `endl` also includes flushing of output stream. it's not just a newline char.

Comment: Just read it! Beware that your call to `ignore` is wrong as it stops at the `\n` not reading it. Use `getline` to read a line.

Comment: Input operations with `>>` skip whitespace,, including newlines, automatically. If you want to read line-by-line instead, you should use `getline`.

Comment: `endl` doesn't do what you think it does. Otherwise, this isn't a terrible idea actually. I saw somewhere a decent code sample for extracting from istream with structure; wish I could remember where it was.

Comment: Do you mean skipping just the end-of-line (`'\n'`) symbol or the rest of the line (as your example based on `ignore()` suggests)?

Comment: I don't think there's any fundamental reason that they couldn't have built `endl` to do that. I think they just chose not to.

Comment: `std::endl` writes a newline character and flushes the output buffer. What do you want it to do as an input manipulator?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: precisely what I want: flushing the input stream.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: no, getline requires a string argument an reports the line content. I don't want it.

Comment: @PeteBecker: flush until and including the end-of-line character. Just like a Pascal's readln.

Comment: flushing and skipping is not really the same. There is no *flush* for input streams, you have to read or seek (if the stream is able to).

Answer (score 3):

> ... skipping the end of the line.
>
> ...  we have to use the ugly
>
> ```
> In.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
> ```

The quoted program doesn't just "skip the end of the line" (character). It skips the entire rest of the line. Indeed, as far as I know, there is no simpler way to skip the rest of the line, but if you find this ugly, you can write a helper function so that you don't need to repeat the ugly code.

If you simply intend to skip just the end of the line character, then following is sufficient, and quite less ugly

```
In.ignore(1, '\n');
```

> Why is there no endl specifier for an input stream ?

`endl` writes a newline and flushes an output stream. Skipping rest of the line doesn't seem like a logical input stream analogue for that in my opinion.

If you have an idea for better way to express the skipping of the end (or rest?) of the line, then feel free to suggest an alternative. While I personally would welcome your proposal here, that hardly furthers the chance of such proposal being adopted by the standard. For that, you should propose to the committee.

Comment: I wrote "skip the end of the line" instead of "end-of-line" (character) on purpose, I am perfectly aware of that. It is a pity that there is no simple construction to achieve that. `endl` would have been elegant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm sure you are aware of what you meant, but I wasn't, and I'm sure that many others were neihter. *End of the line* is ambiguous. I agree that it would be nice to have something like Leon's  `skip_till_endl` in the standard library, but we don't have it. If you feel that it is important, then you can of course write a proposal.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own input stream manipulator as follows:

```
std::istream& skip_till_endl(std::istream& in)
{
    in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    return in;
}
```

Usage example:

```
$ cat main.cpp 
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

std::istream& skip_till_endl(std::istream& in)
{
    in.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    return in;
}

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    std::cin >> i >> skip_till_endl;
    std::cin >> j >> skip_till_endl;

    std::cout << "\n\n--- Output ---\n";
    std::cout << "i=" << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "j=" << j << std::endl;
}

$ make main
g++     main.cpp   -o main

$ ./main <<END
1 abc
2 def gh
END


--- Output ---
i=1
j=2
```